# How to save words that occur no more than 3 times in a text? Reading and writing files

Tags: python, loops, split, tokenize, word-count

I am working on a text file right now that is called "dracula.txt", and I have to do the following in python:

Save words that occur no more than 3 times in descending order in a file called less_common_words.txt. Each word with its count should be saved on a separate line.

I would appreciate any help! I've been working on this for too long.

I have already tokenized my file and counted the words. This is my code so far:

```
file = open("C:/Users/17733/Downloads/dracula.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
data = file.read()
data
data_list = data.split('\n')
data_list 
new_list = []
for i in data_list:
    if i !='':
        ans_here = i.split(' ')
        new_list.extend(ans_here)
new_list 
import string
import re
puncs = list(string.punctuation)
puncs.append('"')
puncs.append('[')
puncs.append('.')
puncs.append('-')
puncs.append('_')
#append each seperately 
new_2 = []
for i in new_list:
    for p in puncs:
        if p in i:
            i_new = i.replace(p, ' ')
            new_2.append(i_new)
new_2
new_2 = [i.replace('  ', ' ').strip().lower() for i in new_2]
new_2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should exactly be what you need- I fixed my previous error by flattening the entire txt into a 2d list:

```
book_open = open('frankenstein.txt', 'r').readlines()
beauty_book = [i.split() for i in book_open]
flatten = []
for sublist in beauty_book:
    for val in sublist:
        flatten.append(val)
foo = 0
for i in flatten:
    list_open = open('less_common_words.txt', 'r').readlines()
    beauty_list = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in list_open]
    count = flatten.count(flatten[foo])
    compile = str((flatten[foo], count))
    if count <= 3:
        if compile not in beauty_list:
            file = open('less_common_words.txt', 'a+')
            file.write('\n'+compile)
            file.close()
    foo += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
import string
filepath = Path('test.txt')
output_filepath = Path('outfile.txt')
# print(filepath.exists())
with open(filepath) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

word_list = sum((
    (s.lower().strip('\n').translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))).split(' ')
    for s in content
), [])

less_common_words = sorted([
    key for key, value in Counter(word_list).items() if value <= 3
],reverse=True)

with open(output_filepath, mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    myfile.write('\n'.join(less_common_words))
```